# binding dropdownlist in repeater's item template using an sql datasource

Tags: asp.net

We are having some performance issues with a page and I wanted to ask about this.  If I have a repeater and in the itemtemplate of the repeater I have a dropdownlist bound to an sql datasource, will that selectcommand be called once per each item even though the same result is returned each time?  If so, as a quick fix, would enable caching set to true and a cache duration specified ensure that that query is run only once per page life cycle?  I know I should be using object datasource, but I want to try to fix this quickly for now.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as far as I know if you do NOT have cache set to true it will be executing the query for each and every databinding call.

Personally you might be better off to query the results, then manually bind it in the ItemDataBound event rather than even bothering with a SQL Data Source, however, if your current concern is getting by with the current configuration caching should help greatly!

**Updated**

Added the following to respond to a comment.

Page_Load executes first in the chain of command, you could declare a page level variable to hold the datatable, then inside the item data bound event you could use it for the binding, something like this if it was CS.  This is only a partial example....just to get the idea across.

```
partial class MyPage
{
    private DataTable _ddlData;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Logic to fill _ddlData and then bind the repeater goes here
    }

    protected void Grid_ItemDataBound() //I forgot the proper parameters here
    {
        //Properly check for e.item.itemtype = Item or Alt item
        DropDownList oList = (DropDownList)e.item.findcontrol("ddlItems"); //lookup for your item
        oList.DataSource = _ddlData;
        oList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think would be the best storage mechanism for storing the datatable of results?  Does page_load run before all of the item databound events so I could query for them in page load and stick it in viewstate or something?

Comment: Added note to answer to respond